# ударение в фамилии Чилышов

Tags: орфоэпия

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, на каком слоге нужно ставить ударение в фамилии Чилышов.
Фамилия старинная. Тимофей Чилышов был кузнецом в городе Клин Московской области в 1886 году.
Заранее благодарю.
С уважением, Елена.

Answer (score 1):

Выскажу предположение, потому что ударение в фамилиях непроверябельно, а Тимофей Чилышов незавикипидирован.

Тимофей Чилыш**о**в.

Как МеньшОв, БольшОв, ЧернышОв, БалашОв, БаркашОв, МакашОв. То есть по прецеденту.

Если бы фамилия имела окончание *-ев,* были бы возможны варианты:

Ч**и**лышев и Чил**ы**шев...

Можно бы попытаться найти в диалектах значение корня "чилыш", но мне это не удалось.

В случае конкретного Тимофея - могла же произойти ошибка в записи фамилии, исказившая и ударение. Он мог быть потомком Челыша...

[**Что означает фамилия Че́лышев**](http://names.neolove.ru/last_names/23/che/chelyshev.html)

> Фамилия Челышев образована от прозвища Челыш. Оно восходит к
>   нарицательному «челыш» — так в некоторых областях называли
>   определенные виды грибов. Скорее всего, оно закреплялось за небольшим,
>   маленького роста человеком. Со временем получил фамилию Челышев.

См. также: **[Челыш (чёлыш)](http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=121520)**

> Ударение: на второй слог. Значение: молодой гриб рода Leccinum –
>   подберёзовик, подосиновик (осиновик), со шляпкой, облегающей ножку.
>   Регион: Владимирская обл., запад Нижегородской обл. Примечание: в
>   сельском употреблении, возм., шире – тж. на севере Рязанской обл., на
>   северо-западе. Статус: регионально разговорное. Происхождение слова:
>   согл. Далю, от целый с диал. ч-. Фиксация в словарях: не фиксируется.
>   Ср. Даль челЫш, челышек [= челышок?], влад. "круглый грибок, молодой и
>   крепкий гриб; подосиновик, с пухлою красною шляпкой" и челЫш, влад.
>   "грибок; […] по местному произношению целыш"; тж. целыш "гриб жёлтик;
>   маслёнок; берёзовик".

Comment: Я бы это предположение утвердил: есть ли хоть одна фамилия с написанием на -шов и с ударением на другом слоге? Если исходный вариант фамилии имел "-ев", то с изменением записи ударение должно было сместиться, напр. Чебышев просил называть себя Чебышовым (на слух без смещения ударения разницы нет, да и произносить неудобно), чтобы его сразу отличали от менее великих однофамильцев.